# Unable to authenticate user with passport local strategy

Tags: express, cookies, passport.js, middleware, setcookie

I am using Ionic2 front-end and Node/Express/Mongo backend. I have configured Passport local strategy to login a User and configured a simple middleware to determine if user is authenticated to access restricted endpoints. This all works fine when I test in Postman client. However it fails when I login from browser and try to access endpoint.  What is see is that the browser (Chrome) returns the cookie value in the "set-cookie" Header, however Passport seems to look for the cookie value in the "Cookie" Header. I tried to set the Cookie header in the GET request from my app but apparently that can't be done for security reasons. How can I get the app to return the cookie value in the Cookie header?

```
Middleware
function userAuthenticated(req, res, next){
  //returns value from Postman; undefined from app    
    console.log(req.get('Cookie').toString()); 
  //returns value from app; undefined from Postman
    console.log(req.get('set-cookie').toString());

    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
     }
        res.send([{"message":"not logged in"}]);
}

Protected endpoint
router.get('/books', userAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
   Book.find({}, function(err, docs){
       if(err) {
           res.send(err);
       } else {
          res.json(docs);
          //next();
       }
   })  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure session mechanizm for passport?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport#sessions
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport#middleware